# How to draw the structural formula for 3-ethyl-5-methyl-3-heptene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, structural-formula

This is the kind of structural formula we need to draw:

[image: 66184171-492-E-4-E24-96-EA-9-D774-B1-ED958.jpg]

I took help from Reddit. Here is the attempt:
[image: 61252-CB0-CA97-4-A20-A366-3-D818-BCC89-C1.jpg]

I have done one more attempt:
[image]

Though the 4th carbon of the left condensed version needs to have a hydrogen added, did not take a picture of that.

Comment: We do not need any unnecessary rants. We only need the question and the attempt you have made. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say but the question is inappropriate! It is supposed to be 3-ethyl-5-methylhept-3-ene. Here's the solution:[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you so very much! Now I know my answer is correct. (Got some help from Reddit before seeing your solution) The thing is, I really am innocent, just copied the question from the worksheet, you can look at the added picture, but I am still glad I was able to learn the correct naming structure for branched hydrocarbons. P.S. Nice handwriting.

Comment: It's not the question that's inappropriate, it's the name doesn't follow *current* nomenclature guidelines. Please familiarize yourself with [How to ask and answer nomenclature questions?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3066) Here it would more make sense to cite a related rule or set of rules from the [IUPAC Blue Book](https://iupac.org/what-we-do/books/bluebook/) to back up your answer.